# Use node_modules inside AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, node-modules

I'v just generated an angular application using Yeoman project generator tool. Generated project has a directory "node_modules". Inside this module are a lot of maybe "predefined functions" for array-diff etc.., and i want to use those functions inside my angularJS application(controllers, directives) only if it's possible.

I'v tried to use those node_modules using RequireJS and Node-Browserfy unfortonatelly without any success everytime i got some error . Example  "filter is not defiend etc...". Is there any Step by Step tutorial to do this module integration into an AngularJS application?

My project structure is:
[image: Project structure]

This is my bundle.js generated by node-browswerfy

```
    (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var myFilter =require('../../node_modules/array-filter/index.js');
},{"../../node_modules/array-filter/index.js":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
/**
 * Array#filter.
 *
 * @param {Array} arr
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {Array}
 */

module.exports = function (arr, fn) {
  if (arr.filter) return arr.filter(fn);
  var ret = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!hasOwn.call(arr, i)) continue;
    if (fn(arr[i], i, arr)) ret.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return ret;
};

var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

This is my controller

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name alam2App.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the alam2App
 */
angular.module('alam2App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

var array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(myFilter (array, function (el, i, arr) {
  return false; // I throw it on the ground!
}));
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

Error message i got on console

```
ReferenceError: myFilter is not defined
```

Comment: Exactly how did you try? Attach some code of your attempt.

Comment: You shouldn't use node_modules, because node_modules folder won't be deployed on the server. For array utility functions use lodash or UnderscoreJS.

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal That isn't correct. Node mudules must exist in the deployed environment. _Using_ existing modules in your code is just OK.

Comment: Thank you! So i should not use those functions in my AngularJS app! I'v just opened underscorejs.org so this is an "helper" library with many predefined functions?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use NodeJS modules in angular at all. However, many modules are ported between frameworks. If you found a node module you wanted to use on the frontend, it's highly likely it's available through bower as a frontend module.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to use underscoreJS helper library in my AngualrJS app.

Comment: @Seonixx Thats misleading. Node modules are perfectly fine to use in Angular, its just that angular doesnt encourage it. npm is a javascript module repository, not a backend or frontend one.

Comment: @MattStyles I didn't say you can't, I said you shouldn't. Yes, of course you could if you really wanted to, but I don't think it's very good practice, especially if you're node/angular app is fairly complex. Of course these things always come down to personal preference, but managing node modules with npm and angular modules with bower (for example) allows you to segregate backend and frontend dependencies so you're not presenting the client with your full stack of dependencies.
EDIT: should have reworded to say "node_modules shouldn't be used for both front and backend module delivery"

Comment: @seonixx you wouldnt be. just use a bundler like r.js and the front end only gets what it needs. using npm as your package manager ahead of bower (or whatever) is perfectly valid. I just think saying 'shouldnt' is misleading, you're offering an alternative way, its isnt better/worse so there is no should/shouldnt.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I guess what I meant was that it's best not to have both backend and frontend modules being served from the node_modules directory without some kind of bundler or similar. I know that a lot of front end developers prefer to use NPM + require (for example) over bower, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is always a good place to start, [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) is well documented and their page referencing the use of `node` and [node_modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) describes exactly what you need to do.

`r.js` creates a deployable bundle of all the code you are using and it doesnt much matter which folder you place it in. `r.js` will bundle all your code into one file, you simple include this in your page and it executes containing all the dependencies you require.

Angular made a poor choice regarding module definition, it wasnt such a terrible choice at the time, just a short-sighted one, so you are stuck with having to shoe-horn in solutions to problems like this. Fortunately the community is fantastic and have come up with multiple solutions. Try searching for ways to combine commonJS modules and AMD modules, or, look for AMD-compliant alternatives to whichever modules you want as dependencies.